# Creating a python pandas function to look in one column for a range of cancer code values and to return the top 10 number of deaths by cancer code

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am stuck on a problem where I have a large dataset with various causes of death. I want to filter by the cause of deaths for certain codes (100+ in total) with character numbers (e.g. F58) so that I can get a total number of deaths by that disease and rank them by the top 10 combined total deaths.

I have posted an example of the csv file data from Excel. Can you help point me in the right direction of how to solve this problem?

[image: Mortality data example]

Comment: It would be great if you post a working example where you load the data from `csv` in pandas Dataframe. Or make a Dataframe with some dummy data. This will help us reply to you faster.

Answer (score 1):

here there are two examples that could help:

```
import pandas as pd

# I will create a data frame from a dictionary for this example
dict_df = {
    "Code": ["A","B","C","D","C","B","B","B","A","A"],
    "Age":  [14, 16, 17, 4, 15, 16, 8, 10, 90, 99],
    "Sex":  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
}

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_df)

# Group by column code
data_bycode = data.groupby(["Code"]).size()

# Sort data_bycode in decreasing order
data_bycode.sort_values(ascending = False, inplace = True) 
data_bycode
```

Another approach is to extract the column of interest and use `Counter` from `collections`

```
from collections import Counter

# Collect data into a list
codes = data["Code"].tolist()

# Get ferquencies with Counter and transform it as a dict
freq_codes = dict(Counter(codes))

# Get a dictionary to create a data frame with columns Code and Count
dict_df = {"Code": [], "Count": []}
for key, value in freq_codes.items():
    dict_df["Code"].append(key)
    dict_df["Count"].append(value)

# Create df from dictionary 
df =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_df)
# Sort values in df
df.sort_values(ascending = False, inplace = True, by = "Count") # Neeeded here because we have more than one column
df
```

I hope it could be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to create a list of the codes you're looking for, then use a mask to filter your dataframe on that.

```
code_list = ['F58']  # add as many as you want

# Filter original dataframe on the codes
new_df = old_df[old_df['Code'].isin(code_list)]
```

Then what it sounds like you want to do is group the data by cause of death and add up the total deaths for that cause:

```
# This groups codes and counts how many occurrences fall into that group
top_ten = new_df.groupby(by='Code').count()
```

Then you can do a sortby() to arrange highest to lowest and slice the dataframe to keep the top ten.

Hope this helps!

Update: 
Tried a toy sample on my machine with this result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response it is not giving the exact output I would like. Would you know how to aggregate the sex together as each mortality cause will have sex 0 and 1 which would need to be added together to get total mortality for each code which is found in one column in the csv file. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing, you can define a custom function for each column. Instead of '.count()', you would put '.agg()'. Inside there you can put a dictionary, where the keys are the column labels and the values are the functions you want as strings. So in this case that might look like .agg({'sex': 'sum', 'agerange': 'count'}). Hope this fixes it!

Comment: Thanks, out put of just ten codes and the mortality number associated is still not displaying. I have created a new data frame that just filters the codes I want (e.g. J and K1, K2, K3), and just need it to rank the top10 highest mortality from one column of mortality, any ideas on how to flip the code for that? Thanks

Comment: Could you post a screencap of what you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I essentially just need the cause column and the deaths1 column listed as the output with deaths1 ranked by highest order. (e.g. Rank 1,2,3,4,5 with the number from the column) Thanks

Comment: You could do 
`output_df = full_df[['cause', 'deaths1']]`
Then do:
`output_df.sort_values(by='deaths1', ascending=False, inplace=True)`

Comment: This will filter out the two columns you want and sort by deaths. You should then call `output_df.reset_index(drop=True)` to get the index to go in increasing order.

Comment: Thanks it is almost perfect, so the only issue is it doesn't take into account the other gender and only ranks by one gender per code of death. How would I be able to link the highest ranking code to its equivalent gender and sum it as the highest mortality?

Comment: Just so I'm clear, is your goal to group all the codes together, and then within each code be able to see the breakdown by gender?

Comment: So I want to group the codes by gender, to gain a total within each code and then rank by highest.

Comment: Ok, check out my latest answer. Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Edits and clarification should not be posted as an answer. Instead, [edit] your question to include these additional clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

This will add deaths by code and sex and create a count within each category. Then you group by code and sex and rank by number of deaths, descending.

```
deaths = df.groupby(['code', 'sex']).size().reset_index(drop=False)
deaths.columns = ['code', 'sex', 'deaths'] 

deaths = deaths.groupby(['code', 'sex']).sum()
deaths.sort_values(by='deaths', ascending=False)
```